# Shell script for "top" followed by pressing 1 , it will give me per core CPU usage

Tags: unix, busybox

I am looking for a way to create a script for below task.

1.top
2.Press 1

It gives me the per cpu usage like below output.

> Mem: 631660K used, 500644K free, 0K shrd, 3972K buff, 313252K cached
>   CPU0: 28.5% usr  0.0% sys  0.0% nic  0.0% idle 71.4% io  0.0% irq 
>   0.0% sirq CPU1:  0.0% usr 37.5% sys  0.0% nic 62.5% idle  0.0% io  0.0% irq  0.0% sirq CPU2:  0.0% usr 16.6% sys  0.0% nic 66.6% idle  0.0% io  0.0% irq 16.6% sirq CPU3: 12.5% usr 87.5% sys  0.0% nic  0.0% idle  0.0% io  0.0% irq  0.0% sirq Load average: 3.87 3.23 2.54 3/335
>   13152   PID  PPID USER     STAT   VSZ %VSZ %CPU COMMAND   949   943
>   apps     R     139m 12.6 28.8 egtpuApp 0 0    26     2 root     RW<
>   0  0.0  9.6 [kworker/3:0H]

I have very basic version of top and other utitities , expect is also not there. In case anyone can help creating a script which could take samples of above command into a file it will be very helpfull.

My top info:
Usage: top [-b] [-nCOUNT] [-dSECONDS]

Provide a view of process activity in real time.
Read the status of all processes from /proc each SECONDS
and display a screenful of them.
Keys:
        N/M/P/T: sort by pid/mem/cpu/time
        R: reverse sort
        1: toggle SMP
        Q,^C: exit

Options:
        -b      Batch mode
        -n N    Exit after N iterations
        -d N    Delay between updates

On my system i am not even able to create toprc file.
Thanks in advance.
-vishal